# Firebase create user with email and password and put data in database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to create users with the function createUserWithEmailAndPassword and then put the data of that user into my database but it doesn't work.. the user is added to my authentication tab in firebase but not in my database. I also don't get an error.

```
registerUser.addEventListener('click', function (user) {
    event.preventDefault();
    closeRegisterForm();

    email = registerEmail.value;
    password = registerPassword.value;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(function (event) {
            var ref = firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).set({
                email: user.email,
                uid: user.uid
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
        });
});
```

Comment: Oh, that's so handy that you didn't provide error message ;)

Comment: @entio there is no error message, the user is added to my authentication tab in firebase but not in my database

Comment: You're not handling the potential problem when writing to the database. You'll either need to return the promise or catch it: `firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).set({
                email: user.email,
                uid: user.uid
            }).catch(function(error) { console.error(error); });`

Comment: This is really werid bug. it even exists now!

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was having the exact same problem. But i used a local function to solve it. Something like this:

```js
createNewUser(form) {
  //create new user with provided data of the form
  this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {
      console.log("User " + firebaseUser.uid + " created successfully!");
      updateFirestore(form, firebaseUser.uid);
      return firebaseUser;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      alert(error)
    });

  function updateFirestore(form, uidNewUser) {
    //push data into firestore using the uid provided

    let data = {};
    data['mail'] = form.email;
    data['name'] = form.name;
    //se empuja el arreglo data en el documento del usuario
    this.afs.collection('users').doc(uidNewUser).set(data);
    console.log(data, uidNewUser);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working actually. Why does this bug even exist ?

Answer (score 1):

You refer to `user.uid` and `user.email` but never define `user`. The return type of sign in method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is a user but you define it as `event`. Also make sure you wait for the db write promise to resolve and catch any errors there as Frank advised.

Comment: hey @bojeil I make signIn with a phone number after i confirm the verification code I call createUserWithEmailAndPassword() but the result is two separate users! How can i Make it to refer the uid from "signInWithPhone number"?

Comment: I am not sure what you are going exactly. It doesn't seem related to this question. Open a new issue for it. After you `signInWithPhoneNumber`. You can use `user.linkWithCredential` to link an email/password credential. Calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` will create a different user.

Answer (score 0):

Working for me:

```
        const val = this.signupForm.value;
        this.authService.doRegister(val)
            .then(res => {
                this.msg = 'You have registered successfully!';
                this.msgType = 'success';
                this.authService.updateUser(val.name, null)
                    .then(suc => {
                        const created = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
                        const user = {
                            first_name: val.name,
                            last_name: '',
                            email_personal: val.email,
                            created: created,
                            updated: created
                        };
                        this.userCollection = this.afs.collection<User>('users');
                        this.userCollection.doc(suc).set(user);
                    }, err => {
                        // console.log(err);
                    });
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }, err => {
                this.msg = err.message;
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [phone, setPhone] = useState()
const [email, setEmail] = useState()
const [password, setPassword] = useState()


const handleSignUp = async () => {

    if (!email == ' ' && !password == ' ') {
        try {
            const result = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

            firestore()
                .collection('Users')
                .doc(result?.user?.uid)
                .set({
                    email: result?.user?.email,
                    phoneNumber: phone,
                    uid: result?.user?.uid,
                    displayName: result?.user?.email.split('@')[0],
                })
                .then(() => {
                    alert('User added!');
                });


        } catch (error) {
            if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                Alert.alert('That email address is already in use!');
            }

            else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                Alert.alert('That email address is invalid!');
            }
            else {
                Alert.alert(error)
            }
        }
    } else {
        Alert.alert("Please Enter Your All Field");
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.